# How do I tell what program is raising a notification in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, notifications

For the past week or so on my work computer, some program has been trying to raise a balloon tip notification and failing.  I see the notification for a split-second before it disappears but it disappears too fast for me to see it.  I configured the notification area to display all icons, but it looks like the notification is coming from Action Center.

Are notification messages logged somewhere?  I have a feeling there's some way I can address whatever it's trying to tell me, but since I have no way of reading the message I have no way of addressing the issue.  The notification happens intermittently; you know how it goes.  I stop working and stare at that part of my monitor and it doesn't happen, only to have it happen twice in 10 seconds once I get back to work.  It's really frustrating and distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm filing this under "mysterious computer problem that eventually went away." I either updated or uninstalled whatever was causing it and now I don't have the issue.

It's been quite some time since your answer, RemyServices, but if you could explain how ProcMon could be used to see what's causing a notification like this? It'd be interesting in case it pops up again.

Answer (score 4):

Check in the Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Event Viewer

In general, background services and background applications should report errors in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals to track this down, that is if this is still an issue.